# Difference in forms between bootstrap 4 alpha 4 and alpha 6

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have the following code:

```
<div class="card">
<div class="card-block">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
            <label for="visualTheme" class="control-label">Visual Theme</label>
            <div>
                <input class="form-control"
                       style="height:30px;width:250px" id="visualTheme" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
            <label for="startingScreen" class="control-label">Starting Screen</label>
            <div>
                <input class="form-control"
                       style="height:30px;width:250px" id="startingScreen" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

That using B4 Alpha 4 was producing something like this:
[image]

But using Alpha 6 it looks like this:

[image]

Here is my
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uvrkuk4p/4/)

Why it's wrapping columns even if there is enough room to have them on the same row? And it does it right with Alpha 4.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `col-*` should always be placed in `row`..

```
<div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
            <form class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                    <label for="visualTheme" class="control-label">Visual Theme</label>
                    <div>
                        <input class="form-control" style="height:30px;width:250px" id="visualTheme">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                    <label for="startingScreen" class="control-label">Starting Screen</label>
                    <div>
                        <input class="form-control" style="height:30px;width:250px" id="startingScreen">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/MtjfuZpqti